How can I spread a class-as-type so that I don't have to manually re-type my parameters with phpstan?
I have the following PHP class that will act as a type for phpstan:
class Item
{
  /**
   * @var string
   */
  public $name;

  /**
   * @var string
   */
  public $time;
}

and my function declaration would theoretically be something like:
/**
 * @params Item
 */
function addItem($name, $time)

where params knows to loop over $name and $time in order to infer their types.
Can it be done?
